# Start firefox in safemode in Ubuntu 9.04

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, command-line, safe-mode

How would I start firefox in safemode in Ubuntu 9.04, I did not see a menu option like there is in windows? Is it done through a command line flag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the command line, run `firefox -safe-mode`.

Comment: tried this before and it didn't work, but figured out you have to have all instances of firefox closed first

Comment: Yes, you have to. There is only one instance of Firefox running, regardless of how many windows you have open. That's an ugly relic of FF's profile system inherited from Netscape but won't change anytime soon.

Comment: firefox -no-remote -P Testing   replace Testing with the profile name of choice and you have 2 copys of ff going.  its a dev option but is possible.  I usually have 4 copies of ff open at any 1 time and 150-300 tabs.